# vue.js does not correctly rerender compared to the vue instance object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, rendering, vue-component

I have a small issue with my vue template. The code is the following :

```
<template>
<div class="panel panel-default" 
    v-bind:id="'panel_'+noeud.id">
    <div class="panel-heading">{{noeud.name}}</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Noeud</th>
                    <th>Poid</th>    
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr
                    v-for="noeud_poids in weightSorted" 
                    v-if="noeud_poids.macro_zonning_noeud_id_2 != noeud.id"
                    is="macrozonningproximitenoeudpoids"
                    :noeud_poids="noeud_poids"
                    :noeud="noeud"
                    :noeuds="noeuds"
                    :delete_callback="delete_final"
                    :change_callback="update_line">
                </tr>
                <tr>
                     <td>
                        <select v-model="new_noeud">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option v-for="one_noeud in noeuds " 
                                v-bind:value="one_noeud.id">{{one_noeud.name}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" v-model="new_weight">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="addNoeudProximite" value="Ajouter"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['pnoeud', 'pnoeuds'],

        data: function(){
            return {
                points: 0,
                points_restants: 100,
                new_weight:0,
                new_noeud:0,
                noeud:this.pnoeud, 
                noeuds:this.pnoeuds,
                weightSorted:this.pnoeud.weightSorted
            }
        },

        mounted() {

        },

        methods:{

            delete_final(macro_zonning_noeud_id_2){
                axios.delete("/macrozonning/proximite/",{
                    params:{
                        macro_zonning_noeud_id_2:macro_zonning_noeud_id_2,
                        macro_zonning_noeud_id_1:this.noeud.id    
                    }
                }).then((res) => {
                    Vue.delete(this.weightSorted, String(macro_zonning_noeud_id_2));    
                })
            },

            update_line(nb_points){
                this.points_restants = this.points_restants - nb_points;
                this.points = this.points + nb_points;
            },


            addNoeudProximite(){
                axios.put('/macrozonning/proximite/', {
                    'macro_zonning_noeud_id_1': this.noeud.id,
                    'macro_zonning_noeud_id_2': this.new_noeud,
                    'weight': this.new_weight
                }).then((res) => {
                    Vue.set(this.weightSorted, String(this.new_noeud), res.data);
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

When the function delete_final is executed on the last item of my list, the view is correctly rerendered as the last item of my list is removed. But when I try to remove the first item of my list then the view rerenders but the the last item has been removed. When I check the Vue object in devtools, it does not reflect the new view, but it reflects the action taken (my first item has been removed).

If you have any idea where this problem comes from it would be awesome.

Thanks a lot community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `key` attribute on the element you are rendering with `v-for` so that vue can exactly identify VNodes when diffing the new list of nodes against the old list. See [key attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-component)

```
<tr> v-for="noeud_poids in weightSorted" :key="noeud_poids.id" </tr>
```

Comment: Awesome, I have spent two days on this ... And I saw the warning in the console but didn't really care ... Thanks a lot for the quick answer :)